# Proguard with AChartEngine

Tags: android, class, proguard, achartengine

I am using Proguard to obfuscate my application.
I use AChartEngine for drawing a linear chart.
Going nuts: after creating the apk and I try to zoom in, I receive this error.

```
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569): Process:
> com.sss.exchangecenter, PID: 14569 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid
> index 0, size is 0 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):   at
> java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> org.achartengine.chart.LineChart.drawSeries(ProGuard:168) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.drawSeries(ProGuard:518) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(ProGuard:311) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(ProGuard:168) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.draw(View.java:15114) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14048) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071) 12-09 02:42:18.739:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:266)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:272)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:311) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2492) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2337) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1968)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
> 12-09 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):  at
> android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at
> android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550) 12-09
> 02:42:18.739: E/AndroidRuntime(14569):    at android.v
```

I added these lines to proguard.txt

```
-keep public class org.achartengine.*.* { *; }
-keep public class org.achartengine.** { *; }
```

Comment: Can you share your code + xml file. Looking at your logs, this error doesn't seem to be due to ProGuard even though there are some traces of it.

Comment: By reading your question, and then your answer, **I'm really confused**. You are basically saying that **the very same two lines** that caused your issue.... magically solved it? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem just adding these lines:

```
-keep public class org.achartengine.*.* { *; } 
-keep public class org.achartengine.** { *; }
```